# JavaScript .push to an empty array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I'm trying to solve the Valid Parentheses, and as described in title, I can't figure how to `Array.push` to work in this context.

```js
function isValidPar(par){
  var stack = [];
  var length = par.length;
  
  for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
    var p = par[i];
    if(p === "(" || p === "{" || p === "[") {
      stack.push(p);
    } else if(p === ")") {
        if(stack.length === 0 || stack[stack.length-1] != "(") {return false}
          stack.pop();
      } else if(p === "]") {
          if(stack.length === 0 || stack[stack.length-1] != "[") {return false}
            stack.pop();
      } else if(p === "}") {
          if(stack.length === 0 || stack[stack.length-1] != "{") {return false}
            stack.pop();
    } return stack.length === 0;
  }
}
```

If I `console.log` right after `stack.push()`, then it shows the element I just inserted. But when I try it anywhere else, like inside `else if` statements or before `return`, it seems like the array is empty.

Comment: Haven't read through all of it, but could it be that your `return` statement is one block too deep?

Comment: It could be you put it after pop.

Comment: Your `for` loop will have only one iteration because you've put a `return` statement at the end of it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a corrected version of your code

```js
function isValidPar(par){
  var stack = [];
  var length = par.length;
  
  for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
    var p = par[i];
    if(p === "(" || p === "{" || p === "[") {
      stack.push(p);
    } else if(p === ")") {
        if(stack.length === 0 || stack[stack.length-1] != "(") {return false}
          stack.pop();
      } else if(p === "]") {
          if(stack.length === 0 || stack[stack.length-1] != "[") {return false}
            stack.pop();
      } else if(p === "}") {
          if(stack.length === 0 || stack[stack.length-1] != "{") {return false}
            stack.pop();
    } 
  }
  return stack.length === 0;
}

console.log(isValidPar('(())'));
```

```
return stack.length === 0;
```

should be checked once the for loop is finished

Comment: That was an absurd mistake! Thank you so much for your help.